# Get data from a specific column when pressing edit on that row in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How do I get data from a specific column that the edit button was pressed on in a gridview?

The following code doesnt work:

```
protected void viewStoryTime_OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource10.UpdateParameters["setEditHoursParam"].DefaultValue = viewStoryTime.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
}
```

This is because the row is not actually selected. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: interesting Im looking for this answer to, MVC make that very easy where you can just pass an id along with the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter GridViewEditEventArgs contains the row index for the current edited row from the gridview.

You should do something like this

```
SqlDataSource10.UpdateParameters["setEditHoursParam"].DefaultValue = MyGridView.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[0].Text;
```

Another way could be implement a RowCommand event where parameter GridViewCommandEventArgs carries the command name, then you should do something like this:

```
void MyGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  // If multiple buttons are used in a GridView control, use the
  // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
  if(e.CommandName=="my command name")
  {
     //Do stuff here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`e.NewEditIndex` has the row index of the currently-editing row.  You can use that to access the row and read the cell data as necessary.